# Forma mas eficiente de buscar modificar un valor en un Dataframe de Pandas con conjuto de datos muy grande

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, eficiencia

Necesito hacer un programa que va iterando por todas las filas de un dataframe de tamaño grande, y modifique el valor que cumpla una condición, he buscado sin embargo no encuentro una solucion que sea eficiente.
El programa itera con `itertuples()` por un dataframe y cuando cumple el `row` una condición, busca en otro dataframe donde depende del valor de una columna modifica el valor de la otra columna de esa misma fila

```
for row in df.itertuples():
    COCD= getattr(row,'CoCd')
    ACCOUNT=getattr(row,'Account')
    AccountsDataFrame.loc[AccountsDataFrame['Account']== ACCOUNT,'CoCd']= COCD
```

el ejemplo anterior itera sobre el dataframe df y luego guarda en `AccountDataframe['CoCd']` el valor de `row['CoCd']` cuando se cumple la condicion de que las `Accounts` sean iguales. sin embargo el programa dura mucho, ya que por cada iteración el busca por todo el `Accountsdataframe`.
Habrá una manera más eficiente para realizar esta busqueda?

Comment: Y cual es el dataframe??

Comment: Como mencioné, lo que uso es el `loc` para buscar y modificar el valor de `CoCd` dependiendo de la condición mencionada donde `AccountsDataFrame['Account']== ACCOUNT `, pero al usar esta función el busca por todo el `AccountsDataFrame`, sin embargo solo necesito el primer valor que encuentre ya que todos los valores en `AccountsDataFrame` son diferentes

Comment: Y al ser un dataframe bastante grande se vuelve muy ineficiente

Comment: Si no pones el dataframe para hacer pruebas muy difícilmente podré dar con la respuesta, pero pon un `break` debajo del `loc`. Si no funciona no puedo hacer nada más

Answer (score 0):

No entiendo porqué estás haciendo `itertuples()`. Puedes hacer el `.loc[]` para buscar.

Imagína que tenemos el siguiente `DataFrame`:

```
df_filtro = pd.DataFrame({
              "col0":["h1", "h2", "h3", "h4", "h5", "h6", "h7", "h8"],
              "col1":[0,1,0,1,1,1,0,0],
              "col2":[22,45,63,33,94,12,19,34]
              })
print(df_filtro)
```

**Salida:**

```
   col0  col1   col2
0   h1    0      22
1   h2    1      45
2   h3    0      63
3   h4    1      33
```

Filtramos y modificamos los datos como has hecho tú:

```
df_filtro.loc[df_filtro["col1"] == 0, "col0"] = "modificada"
print(df_filtro)
```

**Salida**

```
         col0  col1  col2
0  modificada     0    22
1          h2     1    45
2  modificada     0    63
3          h4     1    33
4          h5     1    94
5          h6     1    12
6  modificada     0    19
7  modificada     0    34
```